# Display Jquery .slide() form when Javascript is off in browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I created a form for users to register to my site, it uses Jquery to slide the form into view.
I just decided to turn off JavaScript in the browser to see if my PHP form validation is working properly, but the form is not being displayed is this to do with me setting the form element with CSS (display: none), or is their a tag that needs to be used within the HTML for this situation ?

```
<form class="form" method="post" action=register.php id="register">
     <fieldset>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="username" id="username" />
    <br/>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" />
    <br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <br/>
    <label for="confirm paassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register" />
     </fieldset>
    </form>
```

CSS style

```
  #register{
    display: none;
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#register').slideDown(800);
  }
```

All three files are external.

Comment: Please post HTML and Javascript code. Debugging by guessing is _a bit_ difficult.

Comment: `CSS (display: none)` would do it. Add noscript tags that show the form using an inline style section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert your idea. Use js to hide the form for those with js turned on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing from `display: none` with JS it'll not be visible without JS.

Try to use `<noscript>` to show form or link to register page (eg. with `nojs` param) to handle cases when user got JS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be because of setting `display: none` on the form element.

Answer (score 0):

You should add  tag to handle situation when you don't have javascript. However though keep in mind that you'll have to reload page to show the form in such situation...

Answer (score 0):

javascript and css are not strictly releated, so "display: none" is hiding your form

change the display value from none to visible (un-none) in the onload event

Answer (score 0):

Have JS hide the form. Or use feature detection such as [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to see if JS is supported then only apply the style where it is.  Eg `.js #myform {display:none;}`

Comment: Full feature detection may be overkill if you only want to test for javascript support.